# Sanity check on manual combination generation.

Tags: combinatorics

Hello and good day people,

I would like to seek your advice on a little something I'm working on. I am currently manually writing out combinations for a low level pattern matching system and here is how it goes.

It's a set of 16 with 5 placeholder elements. I've complete those with 1, 2, 3, and 4 placeholders already, and I'm currently on 5 and I'm doing up to 15 placeholders. "None" is the placeholder element.

My personal formula is as follows.

I'm working with this as my starting point.
[image: Starting point]

I have pinpointed the patterns I need to iterate through.
[image: Patterns]

The manual process of it.
[image: Process]

Here's a sample of one of the patterns being iterated.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11177100/5nulls-part2.txt

Here's the complete list of iteration I got from my formula.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11177100/5nulls-quickcomplete.txt

The problem I'm facing is.
C(16,5) = 16! / (5! (16 - 5)!) = 4368. But my formula only brings in 4228.

I've been spending hours checking over and over again trying to find what I've missed. I would really appreciate any advice or assistance. Am I looking at the wrong theory? That the combination formula isn't applicable to this? Or am I just missing out on an obvious iteration pattern.

Thank you for your time spent reading!

Note: I can post the full list of iteration if there is a need for it.

EDIT #1: Added manual process illustration and the completed iteration results as of this moment.

Comment: It would be hard to tell without getting into your code. But based on the text file, I wonder if you are excluding possibilities where you have more than two Nones next to each other. That is, I don't think I saw examples of selections where there were three or more Nones adjacent to each other. I do see that you have that "pattern" above.

Perhaps the best thing to do is to debug your code with smaller numbers.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps the best thing to do is to abandon the "pattern" approach, and write 5 nested while/for loops that select the 5 elements you're replacing.

Comment: Truth to what Simon S says., It should be clear that $\sum\limits_{x_1=1}^n \sum\limits_{x_2=x_1+1}^n \cdots \sum\limits_{x_r=x_{r-1}+1}^n 1 = \binom{n}{r}$

Comment: Hi Simon & Jmoravitz, thank you for your time.

I'm actually currently manually doing it, as in without codes as I'm from a design background with very little knowledge in programming. I will a little more explanation on my iteration process, maybe I could get your input from a logic point of view?

Comment: @SimonS Hey there Simon, I added the full list of iteration for your viewing.